# How to determine deprecated permissions?

Tags: java, android, permissions, manifest, deprecated

I'm working on an android application with a huge source code base.
I don't like it that my application requires not a few permissions, and i started to suspect that there are a few which are deprecated and no longer needed.

The question is - **How to determine if so, and which are really deprecated?**

I tried to remove a suspicious permission off and recompile it (using Eclipse Juno),
and hoped the compiled to mark it as an error or a warning, but it didn't.

Also tried to explicitly run Lint on the code, and it didn't detect it either.

The application compiled and runs on the device, and i guess that will throw runtime exception with AccessDenied when the relevant API will be called at some code flow.

Is there any effective way to detect that API, without browsing all the source code or running the application in multiple scenarios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run your code with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure. That will show you all permissions that are actually used.

Comment: Sounds interesting. But actually how do i do that on my device? to whom to give that flag? when installing the apk?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no. There's no automated way to detect it. The only tried and true methods are removing permissions one by one and testing, or stepping through your code to inspect.

There should be, though. I suspect it wouldn't be that hard to write a script that reads your project code and determines the needed permissions. The hardest part would be keeping it up to date with API changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue you are going about this in the wrong direction.

Instead of asking which permission you can remove, go through the list and generate a researched justification for why each permission is necessary, and which features would have to be disabled if the permission was removed.

If you understand what a permission does, it will not be hard to generate search queries to find the more likely spots where it is being used in at least Java code.  But lots of manifests (and even the occasional SO answer) have permissions which are not needed; it's not uncommon to see requests for permissions which the platform will not even grant to non-system apps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well it works, but it looks like some researchers at UC Berkeley are working on a project to scan Android apps and show what permissions they use. More info at http://www.android-permissions.org/